# How do you handle adding something like Devise authentication in BDD stories?

Tags: bdd, devise

If you have a set of BDD scenarios like:

- User should be able to register
- User should be able to login
- User should be able to reset password

etc., normally you write the first scenario, then write the code to make it pass, and then refactor.

But if you use something like Devise, which, once correctly installed and configured, gives you all these features at once, what is the best practice for that? Because, if you write the first test and configure Devise so that the test passes, the other tests that you write should automatically pass without having failed before. Or is having the tests fail first not strictly necessary in a BDD workflow, and I should just be happy that the tests pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BDD, you should focus on the value you're providing to your users or stakeholders. Logging in isn't really valuable, so I'd give them something to log in *for* first.

Then the scenarios become easy, either:

```
Given Fred is logged in
When Fred buys a book...
```

or

```
Given Fred is on his home page
When Fred buys a book...
```

Logging in has no value, and I apologise for being one of the people who's used that as a BDD example in previous years. Don't log in unless you need to, and certainly don't code it first.

I'd write scenarios for my 3rd party apps only if I didn't trust them, at which point, yes, they might fail. Probably better to simply use them in your own valuable scenarios.

Comment: Well, in the current project, registering and logging in is the first thing the stakeholder wants, because the User is one of the core models, and the sign-up process is a bit more involved than just a simple form. I was just worried, that by implementing this, I get some other features "for free", but I guess, if every feature has a test, then, all is good...

Comment: BDD isn't really about testing. It's about the conversation which helps resolve misunderstandings about the system you're producing. Creating the test is itself a test for the misunderstandings. With BDD it's the conversation, not the test, that's most important. Hope that makes sense!